Does a model from LM Studio learn?
I just started with local AI models, my question is if I download a model and ask for a task and correct it, does the model remember the correction for the next time, I meant, is it growing in knowledge?

No, that is not how current "IA" models work at all.

By default, in almost all cases, your interaction with model persists only through the one chat session, or to put it a bit differently, LLMs are stateless, so they don't retain any of the context input by a user.
Translation :

only messages exchanged between you and the model are used for the following replies, and only during the single chat session. Every time you start a new chat, model starts with no knowledge of your previous exchanges.
there are also limits on how much messages are used for remembering, which is called 'context'. You will see 'context size' in model descriptions, that's what it means. Context can be used for other things too, but that's another topic.

There are technique to achieve longer memory, which is also another topic, try searching for RAG (Retrieval Augmented Generation) and related 'embedding'.
Models can learn, yeah, another topic, check 'fine tuning'.
